# Issues with Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

So Im trying to switch my database from Sqlite3 to PostgreSQL and Im having some issues. In the terminal when I try rails db:create && rails db:migrate this is the error that I get

fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"sportsb_development"}
rails aborted!

This is what my database.yml looks like

```
default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
 <<: *default
database: sportsb_development
```

Im not sure if I have any of that incorrect, I was following a tutorial on how to switch to PostgreSQL. I do have PostgreSQL installed locally and I have pgAdmin 4 pulled up and I have made sure that PostgreSql 9.6 is connected and running.

Im running Rails 5 and have PostgreSQL 9.6 installed locally. Im also on Windows 10.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a user and a password in your config.

Comment: You gonna get a lot of pain in the future if you dont switch to linux

Comment: spickermann when I installed PostgreSQL it gave me a username and I entered a password and when I start the server it makes me give that password.

Comment: Using Linux isn't *imperative*, but it is a lot easier. If you don't want to go the whole way to dual-booting, look at enabling Windows Subsystem for Linux on your machine.

Comment: So would installing and using Bash on Ubuntu help?

Comment: Just install docker and use a linux based image to test your app. You can even use to deploy to production without the need to install dlls and libs.

Comment: @Raphael is docker just like a linux VM or something? Sorry Ive never dealt with Linux stuff before?

Comment: It's a virtualized process but you can picture it like a lightweight VM that supports many systems including linux.

Comment: What @spickermann meant is that you should have `username: <USER>` and `password: <PASSWORD>` under the `development` section. (Fill in your username/password obviously.)